# Retaining Ownership of token contract

Tags: tokens

Is it possible to lose ownership of an Ethereum token contract that I create?

I've read through the Ethereum tutorial (https://www.ethereum.org/token) on how to create a token. However, I find myself questioning whether another user could do a hostile takeover of my token.

Obviously, if they had my public/private key they could get control, but are there other ways.

For instance, if a user owned more than 50% of the tokens in circulation would they be able to claim ownership of my contract?

I want to ensure that the coin is protected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how you design your contract.

If you specify that you (the account that created the contract on the blockchain) are the owner (inside the constructor function of the contract) and you do not transfer the owner rights to another account (by some logic inside the contract or externally callable functions) you will always remain the owner.

```
address public _owner;

function YourContract(){
    _owner = msg.sender;    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The article there was just a case study in which they have created a TOKEN Contract, CROWDSALE Contract, and DAO Contract. i.e., actually you have created a token, and selling it via crowdsale, and sending the money to DAO. The DAO is designed in such a way that to control the funds people with majority shares needs to vote. When someone purchased more than 50% which means they have more power and has more control over the funds on the DAO.

Hope this now clears your doubt.